# Unexpected token when mapping in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm rendering a select element and I need to pass `keyValues` to my component. To gather `keyValues`, I map real object's values this way:

```
 <Field keyValues={clients.map(client => {
     key: client.Name,
     value: client.Id 
})} />
```

But as result I get an error `Unexpected token, expected ;`. The error points to `value`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `{}` is treated as a block, so your code is just identifiers with colons and values in the middle of nowhere... this is obviously invalid outside of an object literal, thus the error.<sup>1</sup>

The reason why is because arrow functions follow a certain syntax. Per the [ECMAScript 2015 Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions):

> **14.2 Arrow Function Definitions**
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> ArrowFunction :
>   ArrowParameters [no LineTerminator here] => ConciseBody
>
> ConciseBody :
>   [lookahead ≠ { ] AssignmentExpression
>   { FunctionBody }
> ```

As you can see, the arrow function allows for a concise body, which may be a block with a function body.

Because you are trying to return an object literal that happens to use curly braces, it is confused for a block and your property names and values are also confused for the function body.

To fix this, wrap the object literal in parentheses for an object to be returned:

```
<Field keyValues={clients.map(client => ({
    key: client.Name,
    value: client.Id 
}))} />
```

The reason why this works is because only expressions can be in parentheses. Per the [specification again](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-primary-expression):

> **12.2 Primary Expression**
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList :
>   ( Expression )
>   ( )
>   ( ... BindingIdentifier )
>   ( Expression , ... BindingIdentifier )
> ```

Since a block is not an expression, it cannot be inside parentheses, so the `{}` is assumed to be an object, thus an object is returned (an object is an expression).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> In your example, `key` is treated as a [*label*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). Since your line of code is an expression (`client.Name`), it must be terminated by a semicolon. Since there is a comma instead, the error is thrown reporting a semicolon was expected but got comma.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple. Need to read on JSX basics.

Comment: @Idsa Well, no this wasn't JSX's fault, but an arrow function's.

Comment: Fair enough. Babel then :)